# Fetching Record from database usin SQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two database tables whose structure is showing below in the image

[image]

Here are some Records in these tables.

[image: Records in Mechanic Table]

and

[image: Records in Airport Table]

and I am using the following SQL Query

```
$query = "
SELECT CITY, SUM(MECHANIC.SALARY) AS COMBINED_SALARY FROM MECHANIC, AIRPORT
WHERE AIRPORT.STATE = 'California'
GROUP BY AIRPORT.CITY
";
```

and getting the following result
[image]

but this is not the required result.

I want to list the total, combined salaries of all of the
mechanics who work in each city in California.

But the result is showing the total sum of all the employees' salaries.

Does anyone know how to complete this task ?
Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't use implicit joins, its discouraged. Use something like `SELECT a.city, SUM(a.salary)
FROM Airport a INNER JOIN Mechanic m
ON a.airname = m.airname
WHERE a.state = 'California'
GROUP BY a.city`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed join condition.

```
SELECT CITY, SUM(MECHANIC.SALARY) AS COMBINED_SALARY FROM MECHANIC join AIRPORT on MECHANIC.AIRNAME=AIRPORT.AIRNAME
    WHERE AIRPORT.STATE = 'California'
    GROUP BY AIRPORT.CITY
```